# Flutter | Navigator.pushNamed I got an error, The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. Try defining the operator '[]'

Tags: flutter, navigator, data-transfer

I am trying to transfer data with **navigator.pushNamed** but I am getting error and I don't know how to solve it.

**My Code;**

**First screen transfer data**

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/resultscreen',
          arguments: <dynamic, dynamic>{
            "totalCorrectGuess": totalCorrectGuess,
            "imageName": imageName,
          });
```

**`Second screen use data**

```
class _ResultScreenState extends State<ResultScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Object? gameScreenData = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(AppTextContants.appBarTitleResultScreen),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              **Text('totalCorrectAnswer: \n${gameScreenData!['totalCorrectGuess']}'),**
              **Image.asset('assets/images/${gameScreenData!['imageName']}.png'),**
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: const Text('data'),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Line of code error**

```
Text('totalCorrectAnswer: \n${gameScreenData!['totalCorrectGuess']}'),
Image.asset('assets/images/${gameScreenData!['imageName']}.png'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to cast the `gameScreenData` to `Map`

```
final gameScreenData = (ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments) as Map;
```

**Update**

In case you don't want to always pass `arguments` use this instead:

```
final gameScreenData = (ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments ?? {}) as Map;
```

Here you first check if it's not null with `??`. If it is null it will use `{}` as default. But then you need to check in other parts of your code whether `gameScreenData` has necessary data or not.

```
Text('totalCorrectAnswer: \n${gameScreenData['totalCorrectGuess'] ?? '0'}'),
Image.asset('assets/images/${gameScreenData['imageName'] ?? 'default'}.png'),
```

Here the same thing as before happens. You check whether or not `totalCorrectGuess` and `imageName` fields are null and if they are assign default values to them.

If you always need the data make sure to pass it every time you route, otherwise use this.

Comment: **I got an error like this. How can I solve this?**

'An exception has occurred.
_CastError (Type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' in type casting)'

Comment: @YakupBilgen When you get this error what are you passing to `Navigator.pushNamed`? Because if it's like the one in your question there shouldn't be a problem. Find other places you use `Navigator.pushNamed` and make sure to pass in the `arguments`. If it needs to be optional check my updated answer and use that instead.

Comment: This fixed the error. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing Map, therefore you can typecast it

`Map? gameScreenData = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as Map;`

And use like

```dart
if (gameScreenData != null) ...[
  Text(
      'totalCorrectAnswer: \n${gameScreenData['totalCorrectGuess'] ?? "default value"}'),
  if (gameScreenData['imageName'] != null)
    Text('assets/images/${gameScreenData['imageName']}.png'),
],
```

Comment: **I got an error like this. How can I solve this?**


'An exception has occurred.
_CastError (Type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' in type casting)'

Comment: do you get this error on runtime? check the update

Comment: Yes, I am getting this error in runtime. There is no error in the editor.

Comment: does update answer solve the issue?

Comment: This fixed the error. Thank you so much.